# Is there a way to auto-generate swagger documentation for Azure Functions in typescript?

Tags: typescript, swagger, azure-functions, openapi

I'm using typescript and node with azure functions for my project. I want to auto-generate the openAPI definition file for my project rather than create one manually. I saw the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aliencube.AzureFunctions.Extensions.OpenApi/ package for handling this with C#, but I cannot currently find a typescript equivalent. Is there a typescript equivalent or do I need to manually create the definition file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not a typescript equivalent. Microsoft has not officially supported this.

The package you show is written by justinyoo himself, a community contributor.

This is the original blog of him:

https://devkimchi.com/2019/02/02/introducing-swagger-ui-on-azure-functions/

(You can see that he only made a nuget extension library.)

So I think you need to manually create the definition file.